# Firebase Google/Fb auth: How to permanently fetch user's profile pic?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am developing an android app. I know i can get the profile pic URI of the current user who is signed-in by doing `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl()` and display it in my app using Glide. This will allow the current user to view his own profile image. However, my app provides functionality where user's can view profile of other users. How do i show profile picture of other users?

My idea is that i need a way to permanently download the profile pic of a user ones he signs up on the app and then store the image in a permanent store like s3. I can then fetch that image via some API.

Assumptions: All profile pictures are coming from Fb/Google auth. Users do not upload pictures directly on my app.

Answer (score 2):

First of all yes you cannot get the profile picture of other user with currently loggedin user Auth object. You can only get your details.
But you can get the profile picture by doing some work around. When any user is signed up on the app, store the image url in the firebase or firestore database in node name 'images' or may be 'users' or what ever you like.
Its simpler than downloading and storing image on s3 and then querying it.

Comment: I can store the URL but that URL is only accessible to the user who the URL belongs to. I don't think other users can fetch image from a URL such as graph.facebook.

Comment: You have to save the image on firebase and then store the url to the firebase database. There is no way you can access the data of others through facebook, only basic info.

Comment: This is precisely what i am asking. How to fetch user's image from google and facebook and store it in s3 or firebase?

Comment: When you signedin through Facebook, Facebook will give you your image url.

Load this imageurl on your imageview. 

From Imageview create image. 

Load that image onto firebase storage or s3.

Add that image url to firebase database.

Its just an approach. You may get more simpler way of doing this. But this will also work.